# how to keep free version data when user buy pro version of android apps

Tags: android

I am planning to make an android apps with free version and paid version. How do I maintain the data in sharedpreferences and in SQLite database so that the data can be reuse when the user buy the pro version?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you use In app purchasing to 'unlock' the Free version to the Pro version. Make  sure you use some kind of Server side signing mechanism though.

If you don't want to do this have [a look at this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3711967/best-way-to-have-paid-and-free-version-of-an-android-app/5013009#5013009)