# Differentiating APK files?

Tags: android

I have an application that I want to distribute a free and paid version for. However, when I try to install them both on the same phone, they both register as the same application. They have different package names, so I don't know how to differentiate them so that they can install as two applications.

They also both have completely different certificates when I signed them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this question:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5013009/547351)

> The Android SDK formally addresses the issue of a shared or common
>   codebase with something called a library project.
>
> Basically, the shared code is defined as a library project, then a
>   paid and a free version are simply two different projects in your
>   eclipse workbench, both referencing aforementioned library project.

Updated link: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you have to firm each app with a different key.