# Android wear application packaging fails with flavours

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, wear-os

I have an application that includes a wear app. All works fine on debug tested with a real device. I can alse create the release apk that packs the wear apk inside it. But only if there is only one flavour on my application.

I want to maintain two versions of the application with different applicationId, but although this compile without errors, in this case the two release apks (one of each flavour) don't cointain the corresponding wear apks.

This is the relevant part of the mobile app build.gradle:

```
    productFlavors {
    Trial {
        applicationId "com.example.myapp.trial"
        versionName "3.0.1"
        versionCode 301
    }
    Full {
        applicationId "com.example.myapp"
        versionName "3.0.1"
        versionCode 301
    }
}

}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.+@aar'
    wearApp project(':myWearApp')
}
```

And this is the correspondig wear app build.gradle:

```
productFlavors {
    Trial {
        applicationId "com.example.myapp.trial"
        versionName "3.0.1"
        versionCode 301
    }
    Full {
        applicationId "com.example.myapp"
        versionName "3.0.1"
        versionCode 301
    }
}

}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:6.1.71'
}
```

Any help will be welcomed. Thanks.

Answer (score 31):

Thanks to the clue Scott gave me this is the full solution:

1.) Flavors must be lowercase

2.) dependency configurations must include flavor**Release**

3.) In Wear app buil gradle, under android{}, we must include **publishNonDefault true**

So for mobile app build.gradle:

```
android {

......

productFlavors {
    trial {
        applicationId "com.sample.myapp.trial"
        versionName "3.0.1"
        versionCode 301
    }
    full {
        applicationId "com.sample.myapp"
        versionName "3.0.1"
        versionCode 301
    }
 }
}

dependencies {
    trialWearApp project(path: ':myWearApp', configuration: 'trialRelease')
    fullWearApp project(path: ':myWearApp', configuration: 'fullRelease')
}
```

And for wear app build.gradle:

```
android {

  publishNonDefault true
......

productFlavors {
    trial {
        applicationId "com.sample.myapp.trial"
        versionName "3.0.1"
        versionCode 301
    }
    full {
        applicationId "com.sample.myapp"
        versionName "3.0.1"
        versionCode 301
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: It wasn't compiling at all before for me. When I did this, it now compiles, but it doesn't add the wear app to the watch when I install the release APK to my phone.

Comment: You must sign both apks separately with the same keystore. Ensure you have the signing sections in both build.gradle

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It was a watch related problem. It decided not to do anything. I rebooted all the devices and it worked fine. :)

Comment: @MiguelSesma is there a way to sign both apks at the same time? +1 from me

Comment: How would we incorporate different buildTypes for mobile and wear?

Comment: How to combine 3 flavors with 3 buildconfigs in both the app and wear project?

Comment: @MiguelSesma At the end what's the working solution for you?

Comment: @arne.jeans For different Build types use something like 'trialWearApp project(path: ':myWearApp', configuration: 'trialDebug')

Comment: @TormodT could you elaborate your question? We are talking about packaging. SO the only important thing are flavours. In debug mode you install app and wear app separately

Comment: @MiguelSesma: Why install them separately when they can be combined? Either way I need them combined in two out of three build types (and all flavours). More details on what I need here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33630929/3328701

Comment: TIP: You can do the same with `buildTypes` e.g.  `debugWearApp`/`releaseWearApp`

Comment: Where are the configurations in your answer? I am still missing code

Answer (score 6):

The flavor of the parent app isn't propagated automatically to the Wear project. You have to map it explicitly.

Instead of this:

```
dependencies {
    wearApp project(':myWearApp')
}
```

Do this:

In your Wear app:

```
android {
    publishNonDefault true
}
```

In your parent app:

```
dependencies {
    TrialWearApp project(path: ':myWearApp', configuration: 'Trial')
    FullWearApp project(path: ':myWearApp', configuration: 'Full')
}
```

Comment: Thanks Scott. The words TrialWearApp and FullWearApp  aren't recognized by Gradle, Should I define them elsewhere?

Comment: Ok, I have discobered that in order of this to work, flavours must start with lowercase letter. Once changed to: trialWearApp & fullWearApp the words are recognized , but now I get a 
Error:Module version MyApp:myApp:unspecified, configuration 'fullWearApp' declares a dependency on configuration 'full' which is not declared in the module descriptor for MyApp:myWearApp:unspecified

Answer (score 1):

I see that you found a solution to your problem, but here is my version that combines build configs with flavors and application suffixes in case you might need that in the future. Could also be relevant information for those who end up googling their way into this post.

app/build.gradle:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'

    signingConfigs {
        debug { ... }
        release { ... }
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sample.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionName "3.0.1"
        versionCode 301
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
            embedMicroApp = true
            minifyEnabled false
            debuggable true
        }
        release {
            embedMicroApp = true
            minifyEnabled true
            zipAlignEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

    productFlavors {
        trial {
            applicationIdSuffix ".trial"
        }
        full {
            applicationIdSuffix ".pro"
        }
    }
}

configurations {
    trialDebugWearApp
    fullDebugWearApp
    trialReleaseWearApp
    fullReleaseWearApp
}

dependencies {
    ...

    trialDebugWearApp project(path: ':myWearApp', configuration: 'trialDebug')
    fullDebugWearApp project(path: ':myWearApp', configuration: 'fullDebug')
    trialReleaseWearApp project(path: ':myWearApp', configuration: 'trialRelease')
    fullReleaseWearApp project(path: ':myWearApp', configuration: 'fullRelease')
}
```

wear/build.gradle:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'

    publishNonDefault true

    signingConfigs {
        debug { ... }
        release { ... }
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sample.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 20
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionName "3.0.1"
        versionCode 301
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
            minifyEnabled false
            debuggable true
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

    productFlavors {
        trial {
            applicationIdSuffix ".trial"
        }
        full {
            applicationIdSuffix ".pro"
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain: `embedMicroApp = true`, please?

Comment: If you set this to true, your Android Wear App (defined in dependencies) will be included in the build for the given build type or flavor. If you want your Wear App to always be embedded, set embedMicroApp = true in the defaultConfig and remove it from the build types and flavors.

Comment: Actually you missed to include: `publishNonDefault true` for the wear module gradle file. 
Can you include that? Without that it gradle will complain and I spend about 1 hour trying to figure that out. 
Your answer thought should be the one accepted as more complete with build types and flavours

Comment: I'm sorry you wasted time on that, my answer was merely a stripped version to focus on the real problem. But I have updated it now to be more complete so that it's more copy paste friendly.

Answer (score 0):

I'll add a bit more to @tormod's answer as he omited some crucial points as to include the `publishNonDefault true`

---

Here are some example Gradle files for packaging a wear module **with flavours and buildtypes.**

### Module mobile `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.app"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 85
        versionName "2.5.2"
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
            embedMicroApp = true
            minifyEnabled false
        }
        release {
            embedMicroApp = true
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            zipAlignEnabled true
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
        free{
            applicationId "com.example.app"
        }
        pro{
            applicationId "com.example.app.pro"
        }
    }
}

configurations {
    freeDebugWearApp
    proDebugWearApp
    freeReleaseWearApp
    proReleaseWearApp
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'

    freeDebugWearApp project(path: ':wear', configuration: 'freeDebug')
    proDebugWearApp project(path: ':wear', configuration: 'proDebug')

    freeReleaseWearApp project(path: ':wear', configuration: 'freeRelease')
    proReleaseWearApp project(path: ':wear', configuration: 'proRelease')
}
```

---

### Module Wear `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
    publishNonDefault true

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.app"
        minSdkVersion 20
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 85
        versionName "2.5.2"
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
            minifyEnabled false
        }
        release {
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            zipAlignEnabled true
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
        free {
            applicationId "com.example.app"
        }
        pro {
            applicationId "com.example.app.pro"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    ...

}
```

Comment: No need to copy my answer and make it your own just to add one line of code that doesn't even relate to the question. I've updated my answer as you requested, so please delete this answer.

Comment: @Tormod Dude I do not copy paste if you see. Fix your head and move your problems elsewhere. You answer would not poduce the result you described, you did not fix it so I had to asnwer for new users. Live with that.

Comment: @Tormod Plus you should not downvote answers that are more complete. You donwvote answers that are not correct. I suggest you read again the SO rules and FAQ. This is not about reputation but about helping each other. But I see you think different with your behaviour

Comment: I apologize for the downvote, that was wrong of me. But it's not about reputation, it's about keeping answers to questions as few and precise as possible to keep from confusing readers (as long as nothing new is brought to the table of course). You gave me 11 minutes to react to your comment, so you can't say I didn't fix it. I did as soon as I could (the day after). But again, sorry for my poor reaction.

Comment: @Tormod its ok man. I also was not at the most clear mind. Both of us lesson learned. Thanks for the answer. It helped me. 
Keep it up!