# wear apk is not deploying when there are product flavors

Tags: android, wear-os, android-productflavors

When  I try to deploy with these `productFlavors`, wear debug apk won't built and it is not embedded into mobile release apk. But after I delete `productFlavors` from mobile and wear `build.gradle` file, it's working as it should.

```
 productFlavors {
        lite {
        }
        pro {
            applicationId 'example.app.id.pro'
            versionNameSuffix '.pro'
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try assigning `applicationIdSuffix` and `versionNameSuffix` values for each of your product flavors. See [Configuration of Product Flavors](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html#product-flavors) for more information.

And if you haven't done yet, add `publishNonDefault true`in your Wear module's `build.gradle` file.

```
android {

  publishNonDefault true
......

productFlavors {
    trial {
        applicationId "com.sample.myapp.trial"
        versionName "3.0.1"
        versionCode 301
    }
    full {
        applicationId "com.sample.myapp"
        versionName "3.0.1"
        versionCode 301
    }
 }
}
```

See this [related SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27387429/android-wear-application-packaging-fails-with-flavours) and [Packaging and Distributing Wear Apps](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/packaging.html#targeting) for additional insights.

Comment: thanks it worked, i also applied                                            
  `dependencies {
    trialWearApp project(path: ':myWearApp', configuration: 'trialRelease')
    fullWearApp project(path: ':myWearApp', configuration: 'fullRelease')
}` thing