# Android app product flavors and Google Play

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-games

I'm building an Android game and I'd like to have a free and paid version. I can add these just fine in my code, but the problems come when I have two different package names:

- you need to add the package name on the Google Play dev console
- you need to add the package name for Facebook

Do I need to have two of everything? Two apps on Google Play, two facebook apps, two Google Play Games with doubled all content (Achievements, Leaderboards)? Is there a way to have one app but an easy way to unlock a "pro" version? Maybe with in-app purchase?

What's the best way to do this? Seems like product flavors arent really flavors if Google Play treats them as separate apps...

Comment: In-app purchases probably the best way.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Android Studio, I would suggest going through [Build Variants](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants) wherein using [Android Library Projects](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/index.html#ApplicationModules) was also mentioned as an option if you will be creating same application.

Lastly, you may also check this SO post - [Best way to have paid and free version of an Android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3711967/best-way-to-have-paid-and-free-version-of-an-android-app) for few more options. Hope something fits what you've been looking for.

Happy coding!